# pygtkscintilla auto indent

Tags: c++, python, gtk, pygtk, scintilla

I'm trying to translate the c++ code and i can't work out what "char linebuf[1000]" is, can some kind sole translate this to python or explain what linebuf is. Thanks! :) Taken from http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaUsage.html

```
if  (ch  ==  '\r'  ||  ch  ==  '\n')  {
     char  linebuf[1000];
     int  curLine  =  GetCurrentLineNumber();
     int  lineLength  =  SendEditor(SCI_LINELENGTH,  curLine);
     //Platform::DebugPrintf("[CR] %d len = %d\n", curLine, lineLength);
     if  (curLine  >  0  &&  lineLength  <=  2)  {
     int  prevLineLength  =  SendEditor(SCI_LINELENGTH,  curLine  -  1);
     if  (prevLineLength  <  sizeof(linebuf))  {
         WORD  buflen  =  sizeof(linebuf);
         memcpy(linebuf,  &buflen,  sizeof(buflen));
         SendEditor(EM_GETLINE,  curLine  -  1,
                    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(static_cast<char  *>(linebuf)));
         linebuf[prevLineLength]  =  '\0';
         for  (int  pos  =  0;  linebuf[pos];  pos++)  {
             if  (linebuf[pos]  !=  ' '  &&  linebuf[pos]  !=  '\t')
                 linebuf[pos]  =  '\0';
         }
         SendEditor(EM_REPLACESEL,  0,  reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(static_cast<char  *>(linebuf)));
     }
}
```

Comment: You can't figure out a simple type declaration, but all the rest of it is no problem? Really?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel pretty much yeah :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a buffer for a line of input text, of type `char[1000]`, i.e. an array of 1000 `char` elements (which are actually **bytes**, because C++ is based upon C, which in turn predates the whole idea of character encodings).

If we really wanted a literal translation of the algorithm, the closest fit in Python is probably something like `array.array('B', [0]*1000)`. However, this initializes the Python array, whereas the C++ array is uninitialized - there is really no way to skip that initialization in C++; it just reserves space without paying any attention to what's already in that chunk of memory.

Comment: any idea how to get this from pygtkscintilla? **Edit** might be better if I ask what is the equivalent, why is linebuf there for? is it for the position?

Comment: What do you mean what is it there for? It is a buffer for a line of text. It holds a copy of text from the editor so that it can be modified and then fed back. It looks like the `SendEditor` function is used to communicate with the editor. I can't even figure out what you mean by "is it for the position?".

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I already knew about SendEditor but didn't understand what the buffer was there for. Thanks for your explanation!